# ASP.Net Webforms, run Powershell script on more than 200 Windows 10 machines where firewall is enabled

Tags: asp.net, powershell, firewall

I need to Change Service user, Start and Stop Windows Services through PowerShell. I am invoking the PowerShell script from an ASP.Net Webforms.
All 200 Windows 10 machines are firewall enabled. I am using following Powershell code segment to change user:

```
 $oService = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Server -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE Name = '$sServiceName'"
 $oService.StopService() | Out-Null
 $oService = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Server -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE Name = '$sServiceName'"
 $oService.Change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,"$sUsername",$sPassword) | Out-Null
```

When the firewall is turned on then the script throws exception for each machine.

I tried to run following command on each machines:
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)" new enable=yes

But still no luck. Is there any way to run Powershell scripts from Asp.Net Webforms where firewall is on for each machines?

Comment: Are these corporate owned machines? You'd have to get the system admin to configure an exception for your desired operation. Odd architecture though - why should a web application be switching services on and off on a client machine? I'd love to know the use case for that.

Comment: @ADyson Probably it's some sort of Active Directory management portal thing built on top of webforms, that sysadmins can use to manage Group Policy and whatnot.

Comment: @ADyson I am working on an old legacy application which initially developed as Dashboard application for critical processes on more than 200 windows machines. Later on this application incorporated features i.e. starting process, stopping process and service oriented activities. I know the architecture is not at all acceptable but still need to incorporate this feature.

Comment: Ok. Well I think the solution is probably as I've described - you need to get a firewall exception enabled.

Comment: We have enabled following 2 firewall inbound rules:
Windows Remote Management (HTTP-in) for private, public and Domain and it worked. Thank you for your help.